# Nature's Prophet: Stygian Desolator vs Assault Cuirass

Tags: dota-2

Situation-independently, which of these items are better suited for Nature's Prophet, and why?

[Stygian Desolator](http://www.dotafire.com/dota-2/item/desolator-67)
[Assault Cuirass](http://www.dotafire.com/dota-2/item/assault-cuirass-1)

Comment: i would say that it is always situation dependent. at least u need to sort out if you want to play a pushing furion or a ganking furion (or both). deso is better for ganking while ac increases pushing alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to disagree with both of your potential answers and instead suggest Medallion of Courage. While it doesn't increase your attack speed or damage, it does serve the same purpose of allowing you to gank by lowering armor. Nature's Prophet (when played properly) is an extremely strong ganker as he can be anywhere on the map at once. His pushing will obviously be weaker as this doesn't affect buildings, but you can easily pick up one of the other two items later.

Medallion gives him the single target focus that helps him gank and also allows him to more easily kill Roshan in the early game. The only time I would consider it a bad pickup would be against many heroes with high base armor or many agility heroes, as their armor rises much faster in the early game as they gain levels.

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be **desolator** it is cheaper and easier to make and when it is done the damage boost will make ganking,farming and last hitting much easier.The damage and -armor will also make you better at pushing,especially when destroying towers.

Cuirass is a good pushing item it makes "creep combat" faster,attack speed and -armor stacks nicely to desolator,but buying it before desolator or completely without it wouldn't be the best choice for Nature's Prophet.Also since it is combat and armor aura for maximum effect it would be more suitable for high HP heroes that can stay longer in middle of fight,or until you get hearth or some other tanky item.

But with Nature's Prophets farming capabilities given enough time you will most likely end up with both items since they make good combo.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say go for cuirass if you need some tank as well. If they have high physical dps I usually go for a Shivas Guard and AC combo which both contribute really nicely into teamfights. But this is only possible if one of my temamates is making their own hex/orchid.

Otherwise desolator is always a solid, reliable pick, so dont hesistate in buying that either!